# Creating random string to represent RGB color

Tags: scala, random-data

Suppose I need to generate random string to represent an RGB color. The string consists of `#` and 6 hex digits: e.g. `#ff0000` or`#cafe00`.

I am doing it with [random data generator](https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/random-data-generator) like that:

```
import com.danielasfregola.randomdatagenerator.RandomDataGenerator._
import org.scalacheck.{Arbitrary, Gen}

def randomRGB(): String = {

  implicit val arbitraryString: Arbitrary[String] = Arbitrary {
    for {
      r <- Gen.choose(0, 255)
      g <- Gen.choose(0, 255)
      b <- Gen.choose(0, 255)
    } yield "#" + r.toHexString + g.toHexString + b.toHexString
  }

  random[String]
}
```

How would you improve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are three ranges of 0 to 255, each represented with max of `0xff` and they all are concatenated in a single value, we can directly take a random value in the range of `0... 0xffffff` and produce the resulting string:

```
implicit val arbitraryString: Arbitrary[String] = Arbitrary {
  "#" + Gen.choose(0, 0xffffff).toHexString
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without 3rd party libs.

```
"#%06x".format(scala.util.Random.nextInt(1<<24))
```

Comment: Good point ! However I am trying to learn about this `scalacheck` stuff now.